# STARTTLS handshake against Apple smtp server fails

Tags: icloud, email, macos, ssl, smtp

Recently, my email setup using Emacs/24.4 + Gnus/5.13 on OX Yosemite
stopped working against the Apple smtp server: `smtp.mail.me.com`.  It
has been working fine for years before.

It seems that it times out during the STARTTLS handshake as you can
see below.

```
$ gnutls-cli --verbose --starttls --tofu -p 587 smtp.mail.me.com
Processed 257 CA certificate(s).
Resolving 'smtp.mail.me.com'...
Connecting to '17.172.34.225:587'...

- Simple Client Mode:

- Received[137]: 220 st11p00mm-asmtp003.mac.com -- Server ESMTP (Oracle Communications Messaging Server 7u4-27.10(7.0.4.27.9) 64bit (built Jun  6 2014))
2 STARTTLS
- Sent: 11 bytes
*** Starting TLS handshake
*** Fatal error: The operation timed out
*** Handshake has failed
```

Does somebody know how to further debug the issue and fix it?

Comment: Does the command `(echo EHLO foo ; sleep 3) | nc smtp.mail.me.com 587` return anything? I'm not able to get a dump of the characteristics of either smtp.mail.me.com or mx[1-6].mail.icloud.com. so I'm not sure what filtering Apple is running. I do get STARTLES to spool.mail.gandi.net so the filtering isn't on my side or ISP side.

Comment: @bmike I'm afraid I'm getting the server signature only. `$ (echo EHLO foo ; sleep 3) | nc smtp.mail.me.com 587
220 st11p00mm-asmtp001.mac.com -- Server ESMTP (Oracle Communications Messaging Server 7u4-27.10(7.0.4.27.9) 64bit (built Jun  6 2014))`

Comment: Recent OS X Yosemite 10.10.1 update seem to have solved the problem.